# How to get details of markers on a Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to programmatically grab the details about the markers that are shown on a Google Map that you didn't generate? E.g. http://goo.gl/maps/PkcTt

Answer (score 1):

Hovering your cursor over the marker should suffice.

EDIT:

Try out the marker reference in the google api:
http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: Sorry, I meant programmatically rather than manually. I've updated the question.

Comment: lol np, I'm not sure what they have for that in their api. You should check out the most recent copy of their javascript api for maps. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example you have given , you seem to be wanting to programatically get the details of places or businesses shown by google. You can use the [places api](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) for this, but you need to initiate the search by inputing the location and types of places to the api , to get the details in return.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but for maps that I haven't initialized myself. For example, on maps.google.com or a map that's embedded on some other site.